# Display one unique row from sql database

Tags: sql, unique

I want to display one unique row from a table which have repeated number of rows with the same value. I have tried this sql query,

```
select  
    table1.activityhp, table2.id, table1.sequenceno 
from 
    ServiceDataElementsNew as table1, 
    VerticalsumNew as table2 
where 
    table1.verticalsumid = table2.id
```

and get the this result:

```
    activityhp                      id      sequenceno
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    New acceptors                   2       6
    New acceptors                   2   6
    New acceptors                   2   6
    Repeat acceptors            3   10
    Repeat acceptors            3   10
    Repeat acceptors            3   10
```

But I want this:

```
    activityhp                      id       sequenceno
    Total new and repeat acceptors  1   5
    New acceptors                   2       6
    Repeat acceptors            3   10
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   **add to query** 

        group by table1.activityhp , table2.id ,table1.sequenceno
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword, which eliminates the duplicate entries.

```
select  DISTINCT
    table1.activityhp, 
    table2.id,
    table1.sequenceno 
from 
    EthioHIMS_ServiceDataElementsNew as table1,
        EthioHIMS_VerticalsumNew as table2 
where table1.verticalsumid=table2.id
```

Refer: [Eliminating Duplicates with DISTINCT (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **distinct** for that as mentioned below :

```
select distinct 
    table1.activityhp, 
    table2.id,
    table1.sequenceno 
from
    EthioHIMS_ServiceDataElementsNew as table1 ,
    EthioHIMS_VerticalsumNew as table2 
where 
    table1.verticalsumid=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DISTINCT` function and you would get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Distinct 
    table1.activityhp, 
    table2.id,
    table1.sequenceno 
from
    EthioHIMS_ServiceDataElementsNew as table1 ,
    EthioHIMS_VerticalsumNew as table2 
where 
    table1.verticalsumid=table2.id
```

Or

```
select 
        table1.activityhp, 
        table2.id,
        table1.sequenceno,count(*) 
    from
        EthioHIMS_ServiceDataElementsNew as table1 ,
        EthioHIMS_VerticalsumNew as table2 
    where 
        table1.verticalsumid=table2.id
        group by table1.activityhp, 
                 table2.id,
                 table1.sequenceno
        having count(*)=1
```

Comment: I have tried that but I'm getting different result.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using ? sql server ?mysql ?oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct and inner join.

```
select
    distinct
    table1.activityhp, 
    table2.id,
    table1.sequenceno 
from
    EthioHIMS_ServiceDataElementsNew as table1
inner join EthioHIMS_VerticalsumNew as table2 
    on table1.verticalsumid=table2.id
```